# Store in XSTATE for accessing across components?

Tags: reactjs, angular, xstate, nomachine-nx

I have component A and component B where in after some selection in Component A, Component B should be able to get update state or selection.
I have allocated separated machines for MachineA and MachineB respectively.
I want to know how to get the context of MachineB in Component B which gets updated in Component A.

For eg.: Component A fetches data from Machine A and updates context of Machine B with selected product.
Now Component B should be able to access store of Machine B which is updated. Any idea how to do this? I do not want to pass state as props.

Answer (score 4):

Lift the state up, and use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Put both machines in the context, so all the components share the same instances of the machines.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some code, you are using `reactjs` and `angular` tags so is hard to know what you have con your code.

Anyways, I'm not sure if you are already invoking the B machine inside the A machine, thats the first step to connect them.
The second step is using the B machine on component B but from the A machine.
On react will be something like this

```js
// A machine file
const AMachine = Machine({
  id: "aState",
  initial: "initialState",
  invoke: [
    { id: "bState", src: BMachine }
  ],
  states: {...},
}


// A component
const [state, send] = useMachine(AMachine);
const AMachineContext = React.createContext(null);

<AMachineContext.Provider value={state}>
  <BComponent />
</AMachineContext.Provider>


// B component
const aMachine = useContext(AMachineContext);
const [bState] = useService(aMachine.children.bState);
```